# How to create two sided many to many polymorphic relationships in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, relationships

I have multiple models which can and can be followed by each other i.e. Business, Agency, Vendor, User.

The schema of the above scenario is as follows:

```
id follower_id follower_type followable_id followable_type
```

**Is there any relationship for the above case in Laravel? How can I create relationship and use eloquent methods?**

Comment: I figure it would indeed be a [many-to-many-polymorphic-relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations). The only problem I see would be retrieving them (which you normale would do with `return $this->morphTo()`, which would return both the resources you follow and the resources which follow you.